# hello-samza demo not compiling

Tags: java, macos, maven, apache-samza

I am trying to follow the [hello-samza](https://samza.apache.org/startup/hello-samza/latest/) basic setup and cannot get past "Build a Samza Job Package". As I am running off of the latest I try running gradle as specified:

```
$ ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'publishToMavenLocal' not found in root project 'hello-samza'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with                                                                              --info                                                                                           or                                                                                             --debug                                                                                          option to get more log output.
```

Then I saw that the bootstrap actually runs that so I thought I could just move to the next step:

```
$ mvn clean package
```

Which, after a bunch of output, ultimately fails:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.819 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-11T16:51:20-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/151M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hello-samza: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.samza:hello-samza:jar:0.11.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.samza:samza-api:jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.samza:samza-api:jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.samza:samza-api:pom:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT from/to scala-tools.org (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools): Access denied to: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/org/apache/samza/samza-api/0.11.0-SNAPSHOT/samza-api-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I then ran it with the -X switch and see a bunch of these errors:

```
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.samza:samza-kafka_2.10:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to scala-tools.org (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools): Access denied to: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/org/apache/samza/samza-kafka_2.10/0.11.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I know I have managed to get previous versions to work for me. Is it possibly related to a difference between linux (my previous env) and OS X (my current env)?

Comment: Consider adding a tag for your OS, since it is non-Windows.

Comment: Done. Thanks @sixtytrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks - using 0.10.1 worked for me too (on a Mac 15.6). 
To be clear, I changed `pom.xml` in the build directory (`.../hello-samza`) as follows:

```
146c146
<     <samza.version>0.11.0-SNAPSHOT</samza.version>
---
>     <samza.version>0.10.1</samza.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to a very helpful user on the dev@samza.apache.org who guided me to look more closely at the pom. I realized that the branch "latest" is pointing at samza version 0.11 which I apparently do not have access to.

I then checked-out the pom in master and it is pointing to the current stable release of 10.1. By moving back to the master branch I was able to compile and move on.